# How to achieve the complex UI using ItemControl in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, user-interface, datagrid, observablecollection

I am working on creating a complex report which almost looks like shown in here [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uf1YD.png)

For this I have create a collection where I will store all the descriptions and its corresponding ratings.
This collection is then I am binding to a ItemControl. The collection will be fetched from database depending on criteria's.
Now my problem is how to fragment or separate single ItemControl to look like shown in image. Should I use multiple collections which will be then bind to different ItemControl ? Can I use multiple datagrids?

I am out of ideas... Any suggestions / examples much appreciated.

Comment: No sweat, just make a collection for each category - Math, Arts, etc. With each being its own ItemsControl (or HeaderedItemsControl) Make your ItemTemplate look like a row with the left textblock  bound to the displayname for your description, bind your values to your radiobutton group or checkboxes or whatever you want to use for your 1-5 rating selections, done. Or if they're not dynamic things, just build it all static and bind accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely do-able. Treat each block (such as Mathmatics, Arts Education etc) as an item, and you're then just dealing with an ItemsCollection. Create a style for how to present each item in that collection, and another style for how to present each property in your block (which will also feature a collection of something.

An example I have of something similar, was blocks which consisted of a heading, and a varied number of checkboxes each with a description. There could be a varying number of these blocks too.

In my view, that displayed these blocks, my xaml looked something like this:

```
<ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" MaxHeight="100">
  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding FeatureFlags, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource FlagGroupsAndFlagsItemsControlStyle}" />
</ScrollViewer>
```

I then had a style for that ItemsControl defined in a resource dictionary somewhere ...

```
<Style x:Key="FlagGroupsAndFlagsItemsControlStyle" TargetType="ItemsControl">
        <Setter Property="Width" Value="Auto" />
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid x:Name="FlagListGrid">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                        <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=FlagListGrid, Mode=OneWay}" IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding Name}" />
                        <ListBox Grid.Row="1" Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=FlagListGrid, Mode=OneWay}" ItemsSource="{Binding Flags}" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
                                 Style="{StaticResource FlagsListBoxItemsStyle}" Background="{Binding IsOptional, Converter={StaticResource YNToOptionalBackgroundColour}}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

And then a style for the items within that templates ListBox ...

```
<Style x:Key="FlagsListBoxItemsStyle" TargetType="ListBox">
        <Setter Property="ItemsPanel">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel Width="{Binding Width, ElementName=FlagListGrid, Mode=OneWay}" Orientation="Horizontal" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>

            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <CheckBox Width="20" Height="18" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                        <TextBlock Width="180" MinHeight="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{Binding Description}" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Unfortunately I can't show you an image of what the finished result looks like, but I hope these pointers could set you on track for your very similar problem